# custom loging framework

Tags: logging, logback

I want to add some of the features like logging per thread basis so that it makes easy to look at log files and insertion of logs into database etc .so i want to make my own custom logging framework which does the above requirements in addition to what logback framework can do .Is it possible to replicate logback source code and add some of my files to meet up the requiremens..

```
<configuration>

<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<!-- encoders are assigned the type
     ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
<encoder>
  <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{5} - %msg%n</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
```

as in the above code i dont want to write the logs directly ..i want to cache the logs and then i should append it ..

Comment: plz help me out any suggestion wud be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you approach is wrong: the combination slf4j and logback can almost do everything, there is no need to reinvent the wheel. Just ask for the features you would like to have and you will see you get your answers.

For your requirement that you want a different log file for each threadd: I do not think this is useful, but anyway: look for discriminator in logback. For example this question here implements different logs on a user base: [howto use the logback discriminator value to filter mongodb inserts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9404106/howto-use-the-logback-discriminator-value-to-filter-mongodb-inserts)